# how to get params from inline javascript

Tags: javascript, parameters

is there a way to get query params like below , in this case is appId

```
<script async src="mydomain.com/sdk.js?appId=587970469219817"></script>
```

and use the params inside sdk.js like below ?

```
const appID = query.params.appId
console.log(appID)
```

Comment: Instead of accessing the "last script" as shown in the accepted answer of the duplicate, you can also use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/currentScript